# react Error with props value passed to apexchart option

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Creating a graph using apexChart.
I am using react,typescript,next.js.
I am getting the following type error at options.

**errrMessage**
Type '{ colors: string[]; chart: { type: string; height: number; }; plotOptions: { bar: { horizontal: boolean; dataLabels: { position: string; }; }; }; dataLabels: { enabled: boolean; offsetX: number; style: { fontSize: string; colors: string[]; }; }; stroke: { ...; }; tooltip: { ...; }; xaxis: { ...; }; responsive: { ......' is not assignable to type 'ApexOptions'.
The types of 'chart.type' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"area" | "line" | "bar" | "histogram" | "pie" | "donut" | "radialBar" | "scatter" | "bubble" | "heatmap" | "treemap" | "boxPlot" | "candlestick" | "radar" | "polarArea" | "rangeBar" | undefined'.ts(2322)
react-apexcharts.d.ts(27, 5): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import React from 'react';

export const Chart: React.FC = () => {
  const ApexCharts = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });

  const barOptions = {
    width: '100%',
    series: [
      {
        name: 'group1',
        data:[44, 55, 41, 64, 22, 43, 21],
      },
      {
        name: 'group2',
        data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 44, 100],
      },
    ],
    options: {
      colors: ['#008080 ', '#008000 '],
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 430,
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: true,
          dataLabels: {
            position: 'top',
          },
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        offsetX: -6,
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          colors: ['#fff'],
        },
      },
      stroke: {
        show: true,
        width: 1,
        colors: ['#fff'],
      },
      tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        intersect: false,
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'] },
    },
  };

  return (
    <ApexCharts options={barOptions.options} series={barOptions.series} type="bar" />
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `type: 'bar'` from your config. It should work without it because you pass the type as prop anyways.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you solve it? You can accept my answer or add your own answer so other users will find it when they have the same issue.